# What format of locale does React Intl use?

Tags: javascript, localization, react-intl

According to the React Intl documentation, to add support for a particular language to your application, you need to import a relevant language file from the `locale-data/` directory and pass it to a React Intl function called `addLocaleData()`.

When it comes to languages like English or French, everything is easy as you have `en.js` and `fr.js` that follow a familiar two-letter code naming convention. However, the `locale-data` directory also includes a whole range of files with three-letter language codes that I've never come across before, e.g.: `agq`, `guz` or `kkj`.

I am looking for some documentation that would help me map these language codes to their corresponding languages.

The reason why I need it is I am currently trying to find language files for Austrian German and Brazilian Portuguese and I simply don't know what codes they are hiding behind. I thought the former might be available under `at.js` but there's no such file and the latter - under `br.js` but that file includes some other language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

It's using [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639), specifically:

- [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) (two-letter codes) for languages covered by ISO 639-1, and
- [ISO 639-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) for languages not covered by ISO 639-1 but covered by ISO 639-3

You can find all of the codes [here](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data). It lists both the ISO 639-1 code (where there is one) and ISO 639-3 code (as well as the ISO 639-2/T and ISO 639-2/B codes, which I believe are obsolete).

---

### Details:

The [react-intl](/questions/tagged/react-intl) tag says *"Combines react components with FormatJS."* A quick search for FormatJS turns up [its website](https://formatjs.io/), which on its [about page](https://formatjs.io/about/) says:

> Industry Standards
>
> FormatJS builds on the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) (ECMA-402), **uses locale data from the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/)**, and works with the industry standard [ICU Message syntax](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) used by professional translators.

*(my emphasis)*

Following the CLDR link takes you to the CLDR page on unicode.org, which describes the format and link to [the download page](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads). Kicking around the CLDR site, it mentions ISO 639-3 language codes. Kicking around their "current work" we can find a UTF-8 list of those codes [here](https://iso639-3.sil.org/sites/iso639-3/files/downloads/iso-639-3_Name_Index.tab), which lists all three you mentioned: `agq` (Aghem), `guz` (listed twice; Ekegusii and Gusii), and `kkj` (Kako).

**But**, in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988389/what-format-of-locale-does-react-intl-use/48988674?noredirect=1#comment93825556_48988674), [user3775501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775501/user3775501) pointed out that the only code he/she had checked (for Welsh) was `cym`, but that looking at `node_modules/react-intl/locale-data`, it was `cy` instead. It's clearly [`cym`](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code/cym) in ISO 639-3, but it's `cy` in ISO 639-1; so apparently, they're using [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) as a whole, not just ISO 639-3. ISO 639 defines two-letter codes (ISO 639-1) and three-letter codes (ISO 639-3) (there was a proposal for four-letter codes that has been withdrawn, and separately an ISO 639-2 which apparently had two parts, T and B, which I believe is obsolete). [This page](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data) by SIL International, the registration authority for ISO 639-3, lists both the two-letter (ISO 639-1) and three-letter (ISO 639-3) codes. On the [first page of codes starting with `c`](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data/c?page=1) we find Welsh, which is `cy` in ISO 639-1, `cym` in ISO 639-2/T, `wel` in ISO 639-2/B, and `cym` in ISO 639-3. (The Welsh name for Welsh is *Cymraeg*, hence `cy`/`cym`).

Looking at `node_modules/react-intl/locale-data`, we can see both two-letter and three-letter codes. For instance, here are the c's:

```
ca
ce
cgg
chr
ckb
cs
cu
cy
```

Looking at SIL International's [list for c](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data/c), we find:

- ca - ISO 639-1 code for Catalan, Valencian; its ISO 639-3 code is `cat`
- ce - ISO 639-1 code for Czechen; its ISO 639-3 code is `che`
- cgg - ISO 639-3 code for Chiga, which has no ISO 639-1 code
- chr - ISO 639-3 code for Cherokee, which has no ISO 639-1 code
- ckb - ISO 639-3 code for Central Kurdish, which has no ISO 639-1 code
- cs - ISO 639-1 code for Czech; its ISO 639-3 code is `ces`
- cu - ISO 639-1 code for Church Slavic, Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian, Old Church Slavonic, Old Slavonic; its ISO 639-3 code is `chu`
- cy - ISO 639-1 code for Welsh; its ISO 639-3 code is `cym`

So it would appear that they're using ISO 639-1 codes where they exist, and ISO 639-3 codes if there is no ISO 639-1 code.

[Searching for "austri"](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data?title=&field_iso639_cd_st_mmbrshp_639_1_tid=All&name_3=austri&field_iso639_element_scope_tid=All&field_iso639_language_type_tid=All&items_per_page=200) in the SIL list just finds Austrian Sign Language. [Searching for "german"](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data?title=&field_iso639_cd_st_mmbrshp_639_1_tid=All&name_3=german&field_iso639_element_scope_tid=All&field_iso639_language_type_tid=All&items_per_page=200) yields a number of German dialects, but nothing identified as Austrian. Wikipedia tells me most Austrians speak [Bavarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_language), which is [`bar`](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code/bar). [Searching for "braz"](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data?title=&field_iso639_cd_st_mmbrshp_639_1_tid=All&name_3=braz&field_iso639_element_scope_tid=All&field_iso639_language_type_tid=All&items_per_page=200) doesn't turn up a Brazilian Portuguese; [searching for "portu"](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code_tables/639/data?title=&field_iso639_cd_st_mmbrshp_639_1_tid=All&name_3=portu&field_iso639_element_scope_tid=All&field_iso639_language_type_tid=All&items_per_page=200) turns up several Portuguese dialetcs, you'll have to figure out which of those is relevant for your target population.

Comment: Just to add that the composite "tags" you most likely need are `de-AT` and `pt-BR`. The regional components are from a separate spec for country codes (ISO 3166) not languages.

Comment: Your answer was very useful detective work (they don't make it easy for anyone) but I have found that the list is not correct in the only one I looked up - Welsh.  It said cym but it is actually cy.  I found it was wrong but checking the node_modules/react-intl/locale-data folder

Comment: @user3775501 - Thank you for that! I've updated the answer. It looks like they use ISO 639-1 (two-letter) codes when they exist, ISO 639-3 (three-letter) codes where there is no -1 code (even though there are ISO 639-3 codes for all ISO 639-1 codes). Which is why Welsh is `cy`, but Central Kurdish is `ckb` (there was no ISO 639-1 code for Central Kurdish).

Answer (score 1):

For language codes see 
[ISO 693-3](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp). Usually language variants are defined based on their language code and variant, for example pt-PT and pt-BR. Not all languages might be supported in React Intl.